# List of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Iam trying to create a list of dictionaries, but seems to me, that i am doing something wrong:

So, I have a list of tuples, something like this:

```
dict = {}
lst = []
cats = [(u'cat1', u'Matilda'),(u'cat2', u'Mew')]
for line in cats:
    dict['cat_num'] = line[0]
    dict['name'] = line[1]
    lst.append(dict)
print lst
```

As a result I am getting this list:

```
[{'cat_num': u'cat2', 'name': u'Mew'}, {'cat_num': u'cat2', 'name': u'Mew'}]
```

Can anyone tell me where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Move the definition of `dct` inside the loop (and don't call it `dict`, since this is the name of the class):

```
lst = []
cats = [(u'cat1', u'Matilda'),(u'cat2', u'Mew')]
for line in cats:
    dct = {}
    dct['cat_num'] = line[0]
    dct['name'] = line[1]
    lst.append(dct)
print lst
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember that `dict()` is actually a builtin Python function that builds dictionaries, so it is probably not a good idea to rename it. Why not do something like,

```
cats = [(u'cat1', u'Matilda'),(u'cat2', u'Mew')]
lst = [dict(cat_num=c,name=n) for c,n in cats]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a dictionary for every tuple. Before you were using only one, shared dictionary:

```
lst = []
cats = [(u'cat1', u'Matilda'),(u'cat2', u'Mew')]
for line in cats:
    d = {}
    d['cat_num'] = line[0]
    d['name'] = line[1]
    lst.append(d)
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `dict` has already been created you are appending a `reference` to the dictionary to the array (`lst`) and altering it for every line in `cats`.

To see this, simply `print` your dictionary for each iteration:

```
tmp = {}
final_results = []
cats = [(u'cat1', u'Matilda'),(u'cat2', u'Mew')]
for line in cats:
    tmp['cat_num'] = line[0]
    tmp['name'] = line[1]
    print "For", line, "the dictionary is", tmp
    final_results.append(dict)

print "The final list is:", final_results
```

All you need to do is create a new dictionary each time, and your problems will be solved:

```
final_results = []
cats = [(u'cat1', u'Matilda'),(u'cat2', u'Mew')]
for line in cats:
    final_results.append( \
        {'cat_num': line[0],
        'name': line[1]} \
     )
```

**SEE ALSO:** ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for other places where this behavior might surprise you.